# Better way to play different background musics on different activities

Tags: java, android, mobile

I'm new to Android Application development and there is so much that I have to learn.
I'm creating an app that has multiple activities. I want to find a way to create a service that can play different background music on a loop based on different activities.

I was trying to to create a background music service like this

```
public class BGMService extends Service {
    private MediaPlayer player;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        String currentActivity = intent.getStringExtra("activity_key");

        // Release the previous MediaPlayer instance
        if (player != null) {
            player.stop();
            player.release();
        }

        // Initialize a new MediaPlayer instance
        player = new MediaPlayer();

        try {
            // Check the current activity and set the data source
            if (MAIN_ACTIVITY_EXTRA_VALUES.equals(currentActivity)) {
                player.setDataSource(getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.background));
            } else if (MAIN_PlAY_HOME_EXTRA_VALUES.equals(currentActivity)) {
                player.setDataSource(getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.hall));
            }

            // Set looping and volume
            player.setLooping(true);
            player.setVolume(0.5f, 0.5f); // Adjust volume as needed

            // Set the prepared listener
            player.setOnPreparedListener(mp -> {
                // Start playback when prepared
                mp.start();
            });

            // Prepare the MediaPlayer
            player.prepareAsync();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (player != null) {
            player.stop();
            player.release();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

And In my  activity I will assign it with a constant like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager2 viewPager2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        onBindingView();
        //for view
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this);
        viewPager2.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager2.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);

        //for background music
        Intent servicebgIntent = new Intent(this, BGMService.class);
        servicebgIntent.putExtra("activity_key", MAIN_ACTIVITY_EXTRA_VALUES);
        startService(servicebgIntent);

    }

    private void onBindingView() {
        viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.vp2Intro);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Intent service = new Intent(this, BGMService.class);
        stopService(service);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

However, my code leads me to some problems:

- When I press the home button the music still running
- when I change to another activity, the current background music is gone

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a Service.  A Service would make sense if you *did* want the music to play in the background, or if you wanted to keep the same music playing across activities.  If you want a new song on each Activity, have each Activity handle the music on it's own.  And to make it turn off when the Activity goes into the background, turn off the music in onPause and turn it back on in onResume.

Comment: Nah. He wants background playback but with life cycle awareness. There's no point to couple Activity with any music playback. Instead have the service and make it controlled by the activity based on its lifecycle

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski He says it playing when he presses the home button is a problem, so he doesn't want background playing.  Although possible he needs to be more explicit about what he does want.

Comment: My point was to not have any player as part of activity and by  "background" playback I did not mean it keeps playing when activity is not visible. You can have player service controlled by activity and end user will not see the difference.

Comment: You can.  There's just no reason to do that, if you don't need background playing why make things more complicated by adding an otherwise unnecessary service?